# Java 1.6 JSSE default SSL session timeout?

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

What is the default SSL session timeout used by Java 1.6 JSSE?

[SSLSessionContext](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSessionContext.html#setSessionTimeout%28int%29) has methods for getting and setting it, but neither it or the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) mention any default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSLSessionContext itself **can't** have a default value, because it's just an *interface*.  You need to look at the implementation to find the default value.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/ssl/SSLSessionContextImpl.java.html indicates that it is 24 hours for SSLSessionContextImpl.

Comment: Good point about the interface, I should've been more specific. 24 hrs is probably correct, I found it to be at least several (> 30) minutes with a small test program.

Comment: @arlehdon sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionContextImpl is the default backing implementation.

Comment: Of course it can have a default value, if it's documented in the interface contract. As a counterexample, `Socket.setSoTimeout()` has a default value, and it's an abstract method.